# Refreshing dataGridView's DataSource from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I made an application that displays some data in a DataGridView control. The data is stored in an SQL database. Since there are a lot of parameters for this specific display, I created another (child) form in the same project that helps the user to add or alternate the data in the database. Both adding and alternating functions work fine, but the data in the DataGridView stays unchanged. I know how to refresh the DataGridView's DataSource, but I don't know how to trigger that function form another form.

I use this function to refresh the DataGridView's DataSource:

```
private void RefreshMyDGV()
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyDataBase";
    SDA.SelectCommand = command;
    SDA.Fill(myDataTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataTable;
}
```

I tried to change this function into a public static function so I would be able to access it from the other (child) form, but then the compiler throws errors "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

I also tried to define the DataGridView as public, and then access it from the other form:

```
((Form1)fr1).dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

But that didn't work either.

Please suggest a way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: When you say "I tried to change this function into a public static function so I would be able to access it from the other (child) form" it sounds like you don't have a reference to the instance of the original form. Is that true? In that case, what is fr1? You should be able to make the function to refresh the grid a public instance member and call that instance member with no problems. What happens if you set the datasource to null - does it clear the grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are making the function `static`. You don't need to do that - just make it `public`.

See this documentation on the difference between static and instance methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx

In order to call a public function, you will need a reference to the parent form *instance* (not just the class) from your child form. Add a property to your child form called `LogicalParent` of type `ParentForm` (substitute your actual parent form's type) (there's already properties named `Parent` and `ParentForm`, but they're used for something else and you should not use them):

```
public ParentForm LogicalParent{ get; set; }
```

Now, on the parent form, when you open a new instance of the child form, set this property just before calling the Show function:

```
ChildForm l_childForm = new ChildForm();
l_childForm.LogicalParent = this;
l_childForm.Show();
```

Now, on the child form, you have a reference to the parent. You can now call public functions:

```
this.LogicalParent.RefreshMyDGV();
```

---

Alternative:

On the parent form, pass a reference to the parent form to the `ShowDialog` function:

```
ChildForm l_childForm = new ChildForm();
l_childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Now, on the child window, you can access the parent form via the `Owner` property. But you will need to cast the `Owner` property to you parent form's type. So, in the child form:

```
((ParentForm)this.Owner).RefreshMyDGV();
```

---

MDI:

If you are using an MDI environment (ignore this if you don't know what that is), then you can use the `ParentForm` property in the same way that you used the `Owner` property above (you will need to cast it to the parent's type). MDI environment are more complicated to explain, and since you haven't said that's what you are using I won't explain it here. If you need more information, visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx

Comment: I did that, and it throws the "Non static field required" error again

Comment: Sorry, there are apparently some problems with this site, it didn't show me your entire answer. Adding the LogicalParent worked perfectly, and the problem is solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NDraskovic - not a problem with the site. I posted an initial response then added more detail in subsequent updates. If you hadn't refreshed the page, then you wouldn't have seen the edits (thus my response, suggesting you refresh the page)

Answer (score 0):

I would make the RefreshMyDGV() method public. You can then access it through the parent on your child form.

Since you change the data resetting the binding should do the trick.

```
dataGridView1.ResetBindings()
```

Comment: What do you mean by accessing trough the parent? Could you give me a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the child Form's DialogResult

Then Instead of `childform.Show();`

you'd use       `childform.ShowDialog();`

The ParentForm will now wait for the DialogResult before it continues

Where you alter the database in the childform succesfully you can set the Dialogresult

In childForm:

```
try
{

//alter database

//set DialogResult
this.Dialogresult = DialogResult.OK;

}

catch(System.Exception)
{
//Error Message
this.Dialogresult = DialogResult.NO;
}
```

In parentForm:

```
ChildForm cf = new ChildForm();
cf.ShowDialog();

if(cf.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK)
{
    //SET DATASOURCE
}
```